# Geometric intuition of residuals sample variance as a ratio of two determinants

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, variance, multivariate-analysis, multivariate-regression

We are estimating a regression 
$$
y_i = \hat\beta_1 + \hat\beta_2 x_i + ... + \hat\beta_k z_i + \hat u_i
$$

I am searching for the geometrical intuition behind the formula
$$
sVar(\hat u) = \frac{\det sVar(A)}{\det sVar(A_{-y})},
$$
where

- $\hat u$ are residuals;
- $sVar(\hat u)$ — sample variance of residuals
- $sVar(A)$ — sample covariance matrix of all variables (inluding $y$)
- $sVar(A_{-y})$ — sample covariance matrix of all regressors

It seems it is like a height of something?